# Binding EntranceThemeTransition Properties of Grid in MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate Not Working

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a map control with map items bound like this:

```
<maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MapObjects}">
    <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid   
               maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}"
               maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding AnchorPoint}" >
                   <Grid.Transitions>
                       <TransitionCollection>
                            <EntranceThemeTransition 
                                 FromVerticalOffset="{Binding VerticalOffset}" 
                                 FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding HorizontalOffset}" />
                       </TransitionCollection>
                   </Grid.Transitions>
               ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </maps:MapItemsControl>
```

What I wanted to achieve is to make the map items have some nice animation so they don't just appear out of nowhere...Specifically I wanted them to slide into place in a direction towards the center of the map.

But this code doesn't seem to work...the Binding doesn't even get 'called' for the two properties of `EntranceThemeTransition` and they retain their default values so that every map item slides in from the right.

Also when I change the Binding statement to some property that doesn't exist in my ViewModel: `FromVerticalOffset="{Binding NonExistentProperty}`, there is no error indicating this which would normally happen and would look something like this: `Error: BindingExpression path error: 'NonExistentProperty' property not found on 'IMS_Mobile.ViewModels.MapViewModel+MapItem...'`

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Just to note that I gave a bounty because my problem is similar though more simple - Binding to the same FromHorizontalOffset, but it is in TextBlock.Transitions.

Comment: The map control of WP8.1 is full of bugs, so be prepared that this might not work at all.

Comment: That is quite weird. What happens if you write custom attached property for `EntranceThemeTransition` ?

Comment: I don't see the HorizontalOffset and VerticalOffset properties on MapItemsControl, which is the DataContext you are binding to - isn't that the issue?

Comment: FromVerticalOffset and FromHorizontalOffset are properties of EntranceThemeTransition, see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.entrancethemetransition)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use MapItemsControl but may be it is like ItemsControl. Remove transition from ItemTemplate and add it to maps:MapItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions just like below:

```
<maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MapObjects}">
<maps:MapItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
              <TransitionCollection>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition 
                             FromVerticalOffset="{Binding VerticalOffset}" 
                             FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding HorizontalOffset}" />
                   </TransitionCollection>
        </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
<maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid   
           maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}"
           maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding AnchorPoint}" >

           ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
 </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thx for the effort, your code causes following errors: The member "ItemContainerTransitions" is not recognized or is not accessible. The attachable property 'ItemContainerTransitions' was not found in type 'MapItemsControl'.